# Firestore sub collection querying data

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am reading the docs and see that FireStore allows sub-collection. Which is great. Consider the following example as mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#subcollections) int he docs.

As shown in the docs I can get the reference to the last doc as follows

```
var messageRef = db.collection('rooms').doc('roomA')
            .collection('messages').doc('message1');
```

In the above example, the id's for docs and collections are typed in.

There are cases when id's are dynamically generated. In such a case how can I know how many collections a doc has? Or whether a doc has any sub-collections. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

On mobile clients, you can't know how many collections or what collections a document has.  There is just no API for that.  You have to know ahead of time what collections may exist for a document, or accept that a query on an unknown subcollection may return no documents.

Comment: well, that's fantastic.

Comment: You can always file a feature request to explain why it's important to be able to do this from a mobile client.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/